# Should Python library modules start with #!/usr/bin/env python?

Tags: python, coding-style, shebang

Should Python library modules start with `#!/usr/bin/env` python?

Looking at first lines of `*.py` in `/usr/share/pyshared` (where Python libs are stored in Debian) reveals that there are both files that start with the hashbang line and those that do not.

Is there a reason to include or omit this line?

Comment: BTW is there anything wrong with just `#!python` ?

Comment: @Kos: yes, there is: it does not work.  At least not everywhere.  `/usr/bin/env` is used solely for portability.

Comment: And also because because the location of the actual Python interpreter will change if you're using virtualenv or some of the other popular tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why some files in `/usr/share/pyshared` have declared the shebang & some do not are easy to explain. Take the files `uno.py` and `pyinotify.py`. The former has no shebang and the latter has.

1. `uno.py` is a python module which will be imported and used in other programs/scripts. Thus it will never be executed directly from the command line.
2. On the other hand `pyinotify.py` contains the shebang and you can see that it contains the following line at the bottom (it can made into an executable if you run a `chmod u+x` on it):

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       command_line()
   ```

You can hardcode the python binary in the shebang, but as others have mentioned, using `/usr/bin/env` will make it more portable.

Answer (score 5):

This line is a Shebang line. For details, please consult the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Basically, it specifies the interpreter with which the file can be executed if directly run from the command line.

There is no need to include this line on the top of a file unless you are planning to directly run it from the shell. Some Python modules (e.g. ftplib) have some functionality when you directly run them. These will have the `#!` line on top. Most don't have such functionality and therefore don't need this line.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your script to be an executable, you have to include this line

Comment: This does not directly answer the question. Please improve your answer.

Comment: If I do not, is there a reason to include this line?  There is nothing executable on the top level, only definitions.

Comment: -1. This answer is incorrect. This line is used to specify an interpreter and not to "make the script and executable". The latter is achieved by changing file permissions (on UNIX).